# Join dictionaries returned by separate functions and assign the joined dictionary as value in another dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have 3 functions, each returns a dictionary. The dictionaries look as below. I want to concatenate the 3 dictionaries into 1 giant dictionary. Then pass this dictionary as a value, and give it a key called 'result'.

get_energy() returns this:

{'Energy': {'biggest_gainer': {'equity': 'McDermott International', 'change': '5.31%'}, 'biggest_loser': {'equity': 'Bill Barrett Corporation', 'change': '-13.18%'}, 'change': '-1.48%'}}

get_materials() returns this:

{'Basic Materials': {'biggest_gainer': {'equity': 'Gold Fields Limited (ADR)', 'change': '3.22%'}, 'biggest_loser': {'equity': 'Jaguar Mining Inc (USA)', 'change': '-5.85%'}, 'change': '-0.35%'}}

get_industrials() returns this:

{'industrials': {'biggest_gainer': {'equity': 'LML Payment Systems, Inc.', 'change': '633.43%'}, 'biggest_loser': {'equity': 'Chicago Bridge & Iron Co', 'change': '-12.07%'}, 'change': '-0.46%'}}

The final dictionary should look like this:

```
{result:{'Energy': {'biggest_gainer': {'equity': 'McDermott International', 'change': '5.31%'}, 'biggest_loser': {'equity': 'Bill Barrett Corporation', 'change': '-13.18%'}, 'change': '-1.48%'}},
{'Basic Materials': {'biggest_gainer': {'equity': 'Gold Fields Limited (ADR)', 'change': '3.22%'}, 'biggest_loser': {'equity': 'Jaguar Mining Inc (USA)', 'change': '-5.85%'}, 'change': '-0.35%'}},
{'industrials': {'biggest_gainer': {'equity': 'LML Payment Systems, Inc.', 'change': '633.43%'}, 'biggest_loser': {'equity': 'Chicago Bridge & Iron Co', 'change': '-12.07%'}, 'change': '-0.46%'}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack the three smaller dictionaries into 1 large dictionary.

```
result = {**get_energy(), **get_materials(), **get_industrials()}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
{
    "Energy": {
        "biggest_gainer": {
            "equity": "McDermott International",
            "change": "5.31%"
        },
        "biggest_loser": {
            "equity": "Bill Barrett Corporation",
            "change": "-13.18%"
        },
        "change": "-1.48%"
    },
    "Basic Materials": {
        "biggest_gainer": {
            "equity": "Gold Fields Limited (ADR)",
            "change": "3.22%"
        },
        "biggest_loser": {
            "equity": "Jaguar Mining Inc (USA)",
            "change": "-5.85%"
        },
        "change": "-0.35%"
    },
    "industrials": {
        "biggest_gainer": {
            "equity": "LML Payment Systems, Inc.",
            "change": "633.43%"
        },
        "biggest_loser": {
            "equity": "Chicago Bridge & Iron Co",
            "change": "-12.07%"
        },
        "change": "-0.46%"
    }
}
```